# Concept of refcursor in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper, toad

Hi just wanted to know about refcursor. I have created a package as follows -
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY APPS.emp_pay_pkg
IS

```
PROCEDURE emp_pay_period_proc(
                               p_user_id in varchar2,
                               p_pay_period_date out sys_refcursor,
                               p_success out varchar2)
   IS
      idx      PLS_INTEGER := 0;

      l_pay_start_period date;
    l_pay_end_period date;

      --Curso c_ap is fetching  the pay period details.


   BEGIN
      idx := 0;
      arempty (1) := '';

      OPEN p_pay_period_date for 
         SELECT PTP.START_DATE PAY_PERIOD_START_DATE,
           PTP.END_DATE PAY_PERIOD_END_DATE

        FROM Pay_period ptp
where tso_td=p_user_id

    GROUP BY  PTP.START_DATE,PTP.END_DATE;      

      FETCH p_pay_period_date
           INTO l_pay_start_period,l_pay_end_period;


   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);

         p_success := 'Records get error out in Array ';
   END;
END emp_pay_pkg;
/

now to display the data for testing i used -

DECLARE
   l_user_id        VARCHAR2 (200) := 'User_id'
   l_pay_period_date  sys_refcursor;
   L_START_DATE DATE; L_END_DATE DATE;
   l_success    VARCHAR2 (200);

BEGIN

   apps.emp_pay_period_pkg.emp_pay_period_proc (l_user_id, l_pay_period_date, l_success);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('l_pay_period_end_date'||'|'||'l_pay_period_start_date');
    LOOP
    FETCH  l_pay_period_date 
    INTO L_START_DATE,L_END_DATE;
    EXIT WHEN l_pay_period_date%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (L_END_DATE||'|'||L_START_DATE);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE l_pay_period_date;


   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('' || l_success);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error :' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Strange part is i used a similar concpet on another package using ref cursor but for that one of my collegaues told me that if u have fetched the curdor and moved it into variables in the package body then the cursor becomes empty so it shouldnt be looped and moved into variable in the anonymous block.

Here somewhere i think it should have worked for the above package also. Can anyone clear my concept ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that I understand exactly what you are asking.

A cursor is, in essence, a pointer to a program that can be executed to return results.  It is a forward-only structure-- you can only fetch the next *n* rows, you cannot fetch the previous *n* rows (unless you close and re-open the cursor at which point the result set may be different if the underlying data is changing).

Because a cursor is forward-only, it is incredibly unlikely that it would make sense to fetch from the cursor in both the procedure that opens it and in the caller of that procedure.  Syntactically, it's perfectly valid to do so.  But that would mean that the caller would never see the first row returned by the query which is highly unlikely to be what you want.  If you want to fetch the data from the cursor in the caller, your procedure should only be opening the cursor.  If you want to fetch the data from the cursor in the procedure, it should not be returned to the caller.

As an aside, it almost certainly does not make sense for any procedure to have a "return status" parameter.  If a procedure encounters an error that it cannot resolve, it should be throwing an exception.  The caller shouldn't be relying on checking a return status, it should be catching specific exceptions that it can handle and letting the rest get propagated up the call stack.  A `WHEN others` exception handler that does not do a `RAISE`, such as the exception handlers you have here, are almost certainly bugs whose only impact is to hide errors and remove the very useful information about where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is correct. Your package procedure does not need a FETCH statement. It doesn't need local variables. It doesn't need a WHEN OTHERS exception handler.

If you want to return a ref cursor, the procedure should just open the cursor.
For example, this is sufficient:

```
PROCEDURE emp_pay_period_proc(p_user_id IN VARCHAR2, p_pay_period OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_pay_period FOR

      SELECT ptp.start_date AS pay_period_start_date
           , ptp.end_date   AS pay_period_end_date
        FROM pay_period ptp
       WHERE ptp.tso_td = p_user_id
       GROUP BY ptp.start_date, ptp.end_date;

END;
```

If I needed to return a ref cursor, my personal preference would be to use a function rather than a procedure. But given the example provided in the question, I don't see that a ref cursor is really the most appropriate design.